# Create FireStore Data Structure

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

myPosts is Collection.
I want to make the data structure as below.

```
< Data Structure A >
myPosts(collection)
   ┣ userID1(document)
   ┃   ┣ postID1(collection)
   ┃   ┃   ┗ timestamp: 2018/09/21/22:22(field)
   ┃   ┣ postID2
   ┃   ┗ postID3
   ┣ userID2
   ┣ userID3
```

In order to make the data structure as above, the code I wrote is below

```
myPostsRef.document(userID).collection(postID).addDocument(data: [
        timestamp_field: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    ]) { (error) in
        if let _ = error { return }
    }
```

However, when this code is executed, it has the following structure.

```
< Data Structure B >
myPosts
   ┗ userID
      ┗ postID 
          ┗ AutoGeneratedID 
                  ┗ timestamp: 2018/09/21/22:22
```

How can I make a structure like Data Structure A?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you edit your question and in the first diagram indicate what nodes are collections, what nodes are documents, and what nodes are fields?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen based on his code, I guess userID is a document, postID is a collection and timestamp is ideally a field which is not possible to apply at the collection

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I edited Data Structure A and I appreciate it if you can see it.

Comment: What I want to do is to create a function that extracts only my posts.
Is it better to make a new question because it is a little off the title of the question?
In answering questions, I would be pleased if you could tell me something that is missing is necessary

Comment: Fields can only exist within a document, which in turn can only exist in a collection. It is also recommended to use fixed collection names, since you cannot query to get a list of subcollections. So I'd recommend: `/myPosts(collection)/userId1(document)/posts(collection)/post1(document)/timestamp(field)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields can only exist within a document, which in turn can only exist in a collection. It is also recommended to use fixed collection names, since you cannot query to get a list of subcollections. So I'd recommend:

```
/myPosts (collection)
  userId1 (document)
    posts (collection)
      post1 (document)
        timestamp (field)
```

You can get this with:

```
myPostsRef.document(userID).collection("posts").document(postID).setData([
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you as always!
The code is also very helpful!